# AngularJs : using $location.path() to change the view but its taking some time to load

Tags: angularjs

I am just doing a regular $location.path to load my template, which will hit my server and change the view.
The template changes simultaneously but the view is taking some time to load.

```
   $scope.xxx= function () {
    $location.path("xxxx");
}
```

Just to cross check I removed all the contents of my view(except a hello world) and also from my controller but I don't know what is going wrong in here.

```
.when('/xxx', {
      templateUrl: '/users/xxx',
      controller: ''
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem $location.path taking time to load the page. I reload using $route.reload() after location.path this work for me.
Below I have mentioned the code that I used.

```
      if (result.status === "invalid"){
          $location.path('/basic-profile');
          $route.reload();
          }
```

Hope this works for you :).